# Error loading data to schema with Marshmallow: marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm brand new to Marshmallow and i have come across the following error that i just can't get my head around.

I am trying to load the following data into the client schema: `{address: "test123", client: "test123", contact: "test123", phoneNumber: "test123", postcode: "test123"}`

From reading other threads there are suggestions that i should be using "json.loads() on the data before passing to Schema.load" but i can't get this to work!

The following is where i try and load the client data into the schema:

```
    # Create a person instance using the schema and the passed in client
    schema = ClientSchema()
    new_client = schema.load(client, session=db.session).data

    # Add the person to the database
    db.session.add(new_client)
    db.session.commit()
```

Below is the model i am using:

```
class Client(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "client"
client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
client = db.Column(db.String(32))
address = db.Column(db.String(32))
postcode = db.Column(db.String(32))
contact = db.Column(db.String(32))
phoneNumber = db.Column(db.String(32))
timestamp = db.Column(
    db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow
)
sites = db.relationship(
    "Site",
    backref="client",
    cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan",
    single_parent=True,
    order_by="desc(Site.timestamp)",
)
```

Below is the schema i am using:

```
class ClientSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(strict=True, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        sqla_session = db.session
        load_instance = true

    sites = fields.Nested("ClientSiteSchema", default=[], many=True)
```

The error i get when attempting to post the data is the following:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\mbonline\mbonline\api\clients.py", line 78, in create
    new_client = schema.load(client, session=db.session).data
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\mbonline\venv\lib\site-packages\marshmallow_sqlalchemy\schema\load_instance_mixin.py", line 92, in load
    return super().load(data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\mbonline\venv\lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 588, in load
    result, errors = self._do_load(data, many, partial=partial, postprocess=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\mbonline\venv\lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 711, in _do_load
    raise exc
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}
```

I appreciate all the help, it's been frustrating me for some time!

Comment: It should work. No need for json.loads() if you're passing client as a normal Python dict. You'd need it to change a string into a dict. You should add the declaration of `client` to the sample code.

Comment: Also, although it shouldn't be related, you should use marshmallow 3. Marshmallow 2 has been dropped for a while, already.